# How to stretch , rotate movieclip or swf in as3 without code?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript-2

Well i am building the script as shown below

http://www.uberprints.com/studio/?pId=AA2001OR&cId=NAT&dec=S

Now click at "add image" and load any image.. The image will be shown on the shirt and the blue border shown around the image comes by-default or is it a movieclip  ??

Secondly the image itself is a movieclip or external swf ??

And i know that movieclip has rotate and scaleX,Y properties that can work here but it seems that these properties are not used?? the script is rotating and stretching it due to container default properties.. Am i right??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the blue border doesn't come by default , you would have to use a specific class to do so.
There is something similar at greensock, can't remember the name but look at the list of classes, you should easily find it. 
http://greensock.com

The image itself is probably a bitmap that has been loaded and is used inside a class where the transform display methods have been implemented so that you can use the handles to manipulate the bitmap.

So you probably have a main class that handles the image display. This class uses a masked container so as to limit the display to the tshirt size. This class will need as argument some form of Object to reference the bitmap being used as it's meant to work with whatever images you throw at it.

Comment: http://greensock.com is amazing library. infact, my friend has recommended me once.. Almost solved my problem. Its ow-sum.